# Weird squares everywhere

Tags: unity, lighting, materials, lightmap

So in unity I have some weird squares on surfaces of certain objects, which are buildings represented by planes:
[image]

I don't know what causes it, I tried changing some settings in lighting and material, but couldn't fix it. This only occurs with one object which is a few planes representing buildings temporarily. The lighting is baked (one directional light).
 Here's the screenshots of lighting and materials tab:
[image]
[image]

Does anyone know what could be the problem and how I can fix it?
Ask for more information if needed.
Thanks.

EDIT: The buildings were imported from blender.

Comment: There is also another planes behind those visible in picture  to stop the light passing as planes are single sided. So every single plane has a duplicate turned 180 degrees

Comment: Don't do that. Set the rendering mode of the Mesh Renderer on each plane to Two Sided and remove the duplicates.

Comment: I don't see where I can do so. I could write a shader to render both sides but then the light will still be penetrating the planes so there will be no shadows.

Comment: my mistake, set the `Cast Shadows` variable on each Plane's Mesh Renderer to Two Sided.

Comment: Ok so I set it to Two Sided but at the end of baking the squares still appear. Do you know if I need to tweak something in the lightmap? Because when I set my directional light from baked to realtime everything looks good without any weird shapes. Currently it's set to Baked.

Comment: I've also noticed that when I select my buildings object in the lightmap settings it says "Object's size in lightmap has reached the max Alta's size."

Comment: Try setting `Compressed` in the Baked GI settings to false. Also, try reducing the `Baked Resolution`.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35448/discussion-between-evil-tak-and-vadim-tatarnikov).

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem! It can easily be fixed by setting generate lightmap UV to true in the import settings of the model.

Comment: John! Your suggestion worked for me! Thank you for asking, and answering, this question almost 7 years ago. Your words are still valid today. (^_^)